# javascript if statement not working when passing get values

Tags: javascript, php

I am using the following javascript, form and php. If i run the form using `action="editForm.php"` the php and form work fine, but when i run the javascript it only does the change of the name. 
the javascript:

```
function updateProduct(){
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var name = document.getElementById("originalName").value;
  var newName = document.getElementById("newName").value;
  var description = document.getElementById("newDescription").value;
  var price = document.getElementById("newPrice").value;
  var quantity = document.getElementById("newQuantity").value;
  if(name != "" && (newName != "" || description !="" || price !="" || quantity !="")){
    var url = "editForm.php?Name=" + name + "&newName=" + newName + "&newDescription" + description + "&newPrice" + price + "&newQuantity" + quantity;

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
    xmlhttp.send();
     }
}
submitButton = document.getElementById("editButton");
submitButton.addEventListener("click", updateProduct);
```

when this js is run and i enter the original name and new name, the name changes, however if i enter a name and any other value, nothing changes, does anyone know why this is?

the form:

```
<form id="dataForm">
  <h2 id="formheader"> Update Name</h2>
    <div>
      <label>Product Name:</label>
      <input class="inputForm" id="originalName" type="text" name="Name">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>New Name:</label>
      <input class="inputForm" id="newName" type="text" name="newName">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>New Description:</label>
      <input class="inputForm" id="newDescription" type="text" name="newDescription">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>New Price:</label>
      <input class="inputForm" id="newPrice" type="text" name="newPrice">
    </div>
    <div>
    <label>New Quantity:</label>
    <input class="inputForm" id="newQuantity" type="text" name="newQuantity">
  </div> 
    </div>
    <div id="theSubmit">
      <button id="editButton">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

the php:

```
$name = $_GET['Name'];
     $newName = $_GET['newName'];
     $description = $_GET['newDescription'];
     $price = $_GET['newPrice'];
     $newQuant = $_GET['newQuantity'];

     if ($name !="" && $newName !=""){
     $sql = "UPDATE PRODUCTS SET P_NAME = '$newName' WHERE P_NAME = '$name'";
     $conn->exec($sql);
     echo 'name was run';
     }
     if($name !="" && $description !=""){
     $sql = "UPDATE PRODUCTS SET P_Description = '$description' WHERE P_NAME = '$name'";
     $conn->exec($sql);
     echo 'des worked';
     }
     if($name !="" && $price !=""){
     $sql = "UPDATE PRODUCTS SET P_Price = '$price' WHERE P_NAME = '$name'";
     $conn->exec($sql);
     echo 'price worked';
     }
     if ($name !="" && $newQuant!=""){
     $sql = "UPDATE PRODUCTS SET P_Quantity = '$newQuant' WHERE P_NAME = '$name'";
     $conn->exec($sql);
     echo 'quant worked';
     }
   }
```

Comment: You're missing `=` signs for the parameters other than "newName" in the URL.

Comment: which variable the other value is associated with?

Comment: omg so annoying, you are correct @Pointy i have been trying all sorts for the last hour to get it right and it was as simple as that haha! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
var url = "editForm.php?Name=" + name + "&newName=" + newName + "&newDescription" + description + "&newPrice" + price + "&newQuantity" + quantity;
```

to:

```
var url = "editForm.php?Name=" + name + "&newName=" + newName + "&newDescription=" + description + "&newPrice=" + price + "&newQuantity=" + quantity;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should escape the parameter in your url

**Problem**

```
var url = "editForm.php?Name=" + name + "&newName=" + newName + "&newDescription" + description + "&newPrice" + price + "&newQuantity" + quantity;
```

**new Code using ** `&amp;`

```
var url = "editForm.php?Name=" + name + "&amp;newName=" + newName + "&amp;newDescription=" + description + "&amp;newPrice=" + price + "&amp;newQuantity=" + quantity;
```

Comment: You're right that the values should be escaped, but the `&` definitely should not be. The parameter values should be escaped with `encodeURIComponent()`.